# How javascript retains the outer function's execution context when an inner function is returned?

Tags: javascript, scope, executioncontext, scope-chain

I'm reading these two blogs: [execution context](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) and [scope chain](http://davidshariff.com/blog/javascript-scope-chain-and-closures/) published by David Shariff diving depth into javascript's execution context and scope chain concept.

One thing not clear to me after reading the above blogs is how javascript prevents a parent function's execution context being garbage collected?

Let's look at the following very simple code:

```
function outer(){
    var v1 = 'variable in outer function';

    function inner(){
        alert(v1);
    }

    return inner;
}

var innerFunc = outer();
```

When outer function is invoked, we get a pointer to the inner function. So at this stage, the inner function is created/defined, but not invoked yet.

According to the blogs, only when a function is being invoked, the scope chain will be established. So before the inner function is invoked, I think there's no pointer referencing to the outer function's execution context. Then how does js engine prevent the outer function's execution context being garbage collected?

Comment: You're essentially asking: "How does a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) work?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner function has a reference to the context it was created in<sup>1</sup>. While the scope chain does not exist until the function is called, the scope chain is not what keeps the outer context alive.

<sup><sup>1</sup>or strictly speaking, there is some chain of references from the inner function to all closure variables it uses. It doesn't necessarily have to keep the entire context alive.</sup>